# Python string not recognize special characters

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a csv with a series of strings with special characters, when it loads looks fine (using `df.head(10)` but when I get the cell using `df.iloc[0].descripcion` appears with some encoding.

I see this:
`depto. interior de 80.15m2, consta de sala comedor cocina equipada, \xc3\xa1rea de lavado, ba\xc3\xb1o completo, recamara principal con closet y ba\xc3\xb1o completo. 2da. recamara con closet.'`

and I need to change it to something like this:
`depto. interior de 80.15m2, consta de sala comedor cocina equipada, área de lavado, baño completo, recamara principal con closet y baño completo. 2da. recamara con closet.`

to load the csv I'm using pandas with `pd.read_csv('../data.csv')`

If I use excel or libre office to open the file looks fine so I think that is the encoding.

This is the code that I'm running at the end

````
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
# split the value 
tokens = df2.iloc[0].descripcion.split(' ')

# Converts each token into lowercase 
for i in range(len(tokens)): 
   tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower() 

comment_words += " ".join(tokens)+" "
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1600, height = 1600, 
               background_color ='white', 
               stopwords = stopwords, 
               min_font_size = 10).generate(comment_words) 
 
# plot the WordCloud image                        
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None) 
plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
plt.axis("off") 
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0) 
# plt.savefig('words.png',dpi=)
plt.show() ```
````

Comment: IF you do `print(df.iloc[0].descripcion)` it should render with the correct characters. This is just how python represents a Unicode string inside memory - the characters á and ñ are outside the ASCII character set, and so need special unicode codes `\xc3\xa1` and `\xc3\xb1` respectively to be represented in the string. Technically, in Unicode, the á and ñ _are_ two 'code points' each - they're just smushed together when the text is rendered.

Comment: Ok, but I need to split and check each of those words. Is that going to affect any analysis that I do with that?

Comment: It shouldn't. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, and it returns a list with the same values like 
```['depto.',
 'interior',
 'de',
 '80.15m2,',
 'consta',
 'de',
 'sala',
 'comedor',
 'cocina',
 'equipada,',
 '\xc3\xa1rea',
 'de',
 'lavado,',
 'ba\xc3\xb1o',
 'completo,',
 'recamara',
 'principal',
 'con',
 'closet',
 'y',
 'ba\xc3\xb1o',
 'completo.',
 '2da.',
 'recamara',
 'con',
 'closet.']```  
Even thought when I'm trying to use a wordcloud module to generate a word cloud I get cutted words like "BA" instead of "BAÑO"

Comment: I've added the code In the original question

Comment: add **font_path = 'arial.ttf'**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with a combination of `df.read_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8')`

and adding in the wordcloud instance the path for arial. (you should download and put the right path)

````
                background_color ='white', 
                stopwords = stopwords,
                font_path='../data/arial.ttf',
                min_font_size = 10).generate(comment_words) ```
````